# In bash: trailing space capture in variable substitution

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

I see this in BASH 4.3.48 (SLES12 SP4) and BASH 4.4.23 (OpenSUSE Leap 15.1) when trying to remove multiple trailing spaces from a variable's value:

```bsh
~> xxx="-O -Wall  "
~> echo "X${xxx%% }X"    # (1)
X-O -Wall X
~> echo "X${xxx%% *}X"
X-OX
~> echo "X${xxx% }X"
X-O -Wall X
~> echo "X${xxx% *}X"    # (2)
X-O -Wall X
~> echo "X${xxx%% \*}X"
X-O -Wall  X
```

I feel that either `(1)` or `(2)` should do the job.

The manual states for `${parameter%%word}`:

> Remove matching suffix pattern. The word is expanded to produce a
>   pattern just as in pathname expansion. If the pattern matches a
>   trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result
>   of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest
>   matching pattern (the ``%'' case) or the longest matching pattern (the ``%%'' case) deleted.

As it doesn't work as documented (or as I understand the documentation), I suspect this is a bug (non matching suffix ("`-Wall`") is being removed in case of "`%% *`") in BASH.
Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `echo "X${xxx%% }X"`, the pattern is a single space: . The longest matching portion for that is just that: a single space. The shortest matching portion is also just that: a single space.

For anything more, you need the globbing operator `*`. But that will match anything, removing the `-Wall`. Bash globbing doesn't support directly have an equivalent of the regular expression `a*`. You'd need [extended globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo "X${xxx%%+( )}X"
X-O -WallX
```

Comment: Your answer is not portable to other shells.

Comment: also, the `shopt -s extglob` should be on a separate line and not part of the same compound statement where an extended glob is used.

Comment: But at least the problem explanation is good.

Answer (score 4):

Use a removal of a prefix within a suffix removal:

```
$ xxx="-O -Wall  "
$ echo "X${xxx%"${xxx##*[! ]}"}X"
X-O -WallX
```

- Remove everything up to the last not-space character - leaving only trailing spaces
- Use those spaces as the pattern for suffix removal
- The inner parameter expansion should be quoted to prevent it from being interpreted as a pattern (not necessary above, but may be useful in other cases):

```bsh
$ bash -c 'xxx="-O -Wall*   "; echo "X${xxx%%"${xxx##*[! *]}"}X"'
X-O -WallX
$ bash -c 'xxx="-O -Wall*   "; echo "X${xxx%%${xxx##*[! *]}}X"'
XX
```

A contrived example, but if the inner expansion is not quoted, the asterisk it includes will be treated as a shell pattern by the outer expansion. Quoted, it becomes a literal asterisk.

---

The behaviour you observed is not a bug, it's just how simple shell patterns work:

```
${xxx%% }
```

- a single space is a single space
- longest occurence of a single space is a single space

```
${xxx%% *}
```

- longest occurence of a single space followed by anything/nothing
- anything/nothing will include `-Wall`

```
${xxx% }
```

- shortest occurence of a single space is a single space

```
${xxx% *}
```

- shortest occurence of a single space followed by anything/nothing is a single space

```
${xxx%% \*}
```

- `\*` is a backslash escaped asterisk and will be interpreted as a literal asterisk
- there is no space followed by asterisk in the variable, no suffix is removed

Comment: One of the most exciting shell questions always has been (especially in nested constructs): "To quote, or not to quote?" Unfortunately the manual leaves several questions open IMHO, so it's usually best to try...

Comment: @U.Windl It is always best to quote (unless you really deeply know what you are doing), that avoids interpreting glob characters (*,?,[) in the string as such: "globbing characters".

Answer (score 1):

`read` may also work (assuming `IFS` contains "space"):

```bsh
xxx="-O -Wall  "
read -r xxx <<EOF
$xxx
EOF
echo "X${xxx}X"
```

Output:

```
X-O -WallX
```

---

- `read` splits input into fields according to `IFS`
- `IFS` by default is space/tab/newline, so this will remove any leading & trailing spaces
- Works on the first line of the variable (may not be suitable for multiline vars, `bash` could use `read -d ''`)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with regular expression matching like this:

```bsh
~> xxx="-O -Wall  "
~> echo "X${xxx}X"
X-O -Wall  X
~> [[ "$xxx" =~ (\ +$) ]]; echo $?,"X${BASH_REMATCH[0]}X"
0,X  X
~> echo "X${xxx%%${BASH_REMATCH[0]}}X"
X-O -WallX

~/src/Perl> xxx="-O -Wall"
~/src/Perl> echo "X${xxx}X"
X-O -WallX
~/src/Perl> [[ "$xxx" =~ (\ +$) ]]; echo $?,"X${BASH_REMATCH[0]}X"
1,XX
~/src/Perl> echo "X${xxx%%${BASH_REMATCH[0]}}X"
X-O -WallX
```

Comment: If you go up to a regex, you might as well capture both parts in only one regex. Please try: `[[ "$xxx" =~ (.*[^ ])(\ +$) ]]; printf '<%s>' "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}";echo`

Comment: @Isaac Actually I'd prefer `[[ "$xxx" =~ (.*[^ ])(\ +$) ]]; printf '<%s>\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` then. Also your proposal fails if the string in question has no trailing blanks; it would give the empty string then.

Comment: Use any that you prefer, my example was meant to **show** that both parts could be captured with one regex, no need for an additional "parameter expansion". Your regex also fails to match if there are no trailing spaces, It seems to me that it is why the exit code `$?` should be checked, don't you think?

Comment: @Isaac I just checked: My code does not fail, as `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` is empty in that case (no trailing space), and bash handles that without complaints.

Comment: So, the output from your code of `1,XX` is correct, right? Well, then, `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` for my (proposed) code should give exactly the same output, doesn't it?

Comment: @Isaac considering your score I'm sure you realized that the `XX` you are citing is the intermediate step showing the match if no trailing space was found. It's empty then. Your code prints the empty string as final result when the input had no traing space.

Comment: Oh, please, In comments there is no space to build a correct answer, I was hopping you could understand what I meant. Having failed, O wrote a more complete and descriptive answer. That should clarify your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

A simple parameter expansion is quite limited in the patterns it could match and remove. To remove several (repeated) characters form the end of an string, the usual solution is to actually first remove everything that is **not** the character in question `${xxx##*[! ]}` (all the trailing spaces). Then, as a second step, removing everything that results from that expansion (all the trailing spaces) from the end will give you what you want (remove trailing spaces).

```
$ xxx="-O -Wall  "
$ echo "<${xxx%"${xxx##*[! ]}"}>"
<-O -Wall>
```

As an alternative, in bash, you could use extended globbing:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo "<${xxx%%+( )}>"
<-O -Wall>
```

Or, also, as a higher level alternative, you can match what you want with a regex:

```
$ regex='(.*[^ ]) +$';
$ [[ $xxx =~ $regex ]] && echo "<${BASH_REMATCH[1]}>" || echo "<$xxx>"
<-O -Wall>
```

Or, as an script:

```
#!/bin/bash

xxx=${1:-"-O -Wall  "}

regex='(.*[^ ]) +$'

if    [[ $xxx =~ $regex ]]          # if there are trailing spaces
then 
      echo "<${BASH_REMATCH[1]}>"   # Print the string without spaces
else
      echo "<$xxx>"                 # if there are no trailing spaces.
fi
```